# Pig Latin Word Count

Tags: apache-pig

I am trying to count number of lines that contain the following words: `'jack', 'hack', 'mat', 'throttle'` in a pig script. I am using Cloudera quickstart vm.

The input file is:

```
09-jack-17,5:00PM;#slowmotion,Tribune Logic hack: how is life in temrs of money Creative hack

14-June-18,7:15PM;#Indiacalling,Horton-NJ Strategic/Halloween One World at Application Deployment

12-jack-16,jfh:er;#temporary, accomodation, osteoporosis, juxtapose, don't misinterpret this awaiting throttle jack
```

The output should be:
hack 2
jack 2
throttle 1
mat 0
I am unable to extract those words and  calculate it's count. What should I do?
I tried the following script which was given by inquisitive_mind:

```
A = LOAD 'Input.txt'AS(line: chararray);
SPLIT A INTO M IF line matches'hackathon,N IF line matches'dec', O IF line matches'chicago',P IF line matches'java';
M1 = GROUP M ALL;
M2 = FOR EACH M1 GENERATE COUNT(M);
M3 = FOREACH M2 GENERATE CONCAT('hackathon',(chararray)M2.$0);
N1 = GROUP N ALL;
N2 = FOREACH N1 GENERATE COUNT(N);
N3 = FOREACHN2 GENERATE CONCAT('dec',(chararray)N2.$0);
O1 = GROUP O ALL;
O2 = FOREACH O1 GENERATE COUNT(O);
O3 = FOR EACH O2 GENERATE CONCAT('chicago',(chararray)O2.$0);
P1 = GROUP P ALL;
P2 = FOR EACH P1 GENERATE COUNT(P);
P3 = FOREACH P2 GENERATE CONCAT('java',(chararray)P2.$0);
DUMP M3;
DUMP N3;
DUMP O3;
DUMP P3;
```

But when I run it in mapreduce or local mode I get the following error:

2016-10-11 09:43:44,084 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Lexical error at line 19, column 0.  Encountered:  after : ""  Details at logfile: /home/cloudera/pig_1476204218406.log

Here is the logfile:

### Pig Stack Trace

```
ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Lexical error at line 19, column 0.  Encountered: <EOF> after : ""

org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 19, column 0.  Encountered: <EOF> after : ""
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParserTokenManager.getNextToken(PigScriptParserTokenManager.java:3326)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.jj_ntk(PigScriptParser.java:1379)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:106)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:198)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:173)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:84)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:613)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Comment: First you should show us the code you wrote to do this and then explain specifically which specific part is not working correctly

Answer (score 0):

If the words are fixed and small in number you can use `split` and count the lines.

```
A = LOAD 'data.txt' AS (line:chararray);
SPLIT A INTO M IF line matches 'jack', N IF line matches 'hack',O IF line matches 'throttle', P IF line matches 'mat';

M1 = GROUP M ALL;
M2 = FOREACH M1 COUNT(M); 
M3 = FOREACH M2 GENERATE CONCAT('jack ',(chararray)M2.$0); 

N1 = GROUP N ALL;
N2 = FOREACH N1 COUNT(N); 
N3 = FOREACH N2 GENERATE CONCAT('hack ',(chararray)N2.$0);

O1 = GROUP O ALL;
O2 = FOREACH O1 COUNT(O); 
O3 = FOREACH O2 GENERATE CONCAT('throttle ',(chararray)O2.$0);

P1 = GROUP P ALL;
P2 = FOREACH P1 COUNT(P); 
P3 = FOREACH P2 GENERATE CONCAT('mat ',(chararray)P2.$0);

DUMP M3;
DUMP N3;
DUMP O3;
DUMP P3;
```

Comment: inquisitive_mind  Thank you for your help. But while executing DUMP CONCAT('jack', M2)  there is an error: Cannot expand macro 'CONCAT'. Reason: Macro must be defined before expansion.

Comment: When I execute M3 there is a syntax error  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near 'FLATTEN'

Comment: @HarishSwamy I've corrected it.Hopefully it should work.Don;t have access to the cluster to test it out.If it doesn't work, you will have to figure it out.All I am doing is trying to concatenate the string with the count.

Comment: @ inquisitive_mind. The job runs successfully. But when I check the output which is wriiten  to a temp file in tmp directory; the file is empty. Thank you for your assistance

Comment: What are you using to write the output to temp files? DUMP writes to the console and the results are not persisted.

Comment: ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Lexical error at line 19, column 0.  Encountered: <EOF> after : ""

Comment: ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Lexical error at line 19, column 0.  Encountered: <EOF> after : ""  
I tried to

Comment: @ inquisitive_mind I have edited my question and mentioned the error.