# In pig, how do I count the number of lines that contained a specific string?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Suppose I have a group of target words:

```
a b c d
```

and an input file:

```
a d f s g e
12399
c a d i f
a 2
```

then I should return:

```
a 3
b 0
c 1
d 2
```

How can I do that in pig? Thank you!

Comment: Is the number of target words fixed?I;ve answered a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39962608/pig-latin-word-count

Comment: Yes same question, word count may be a confusing name though...what if the number of target words is rather large?

Comment: You can either store those words in another relation,join the input with the relation,group and count or parameterize your pig script and pass in the search word from a batch script in a loop and get the counts and merge the results.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm trying to do, but I'm having a little trouble. I tried to tokenize the input file line by line, and then use 'join' to get count. However this gives me unexpected answer. For example, for a line like 'b c d a', if I tokenize it and then try to join 'a', the result will be empty. My code was like `A = FOREACH input GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(line)) AS token`

Comment: `B = JOIN keyWords by keyWord, A by token` this join returns nothing.

Comment: In my understanding, A should be a sequence of tokens, and B will give my `(keyWord, {sequence of tokens, ...})`, however it returns nothing. Could you please explain to me what exactly is A and how should I do the join? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First remove the duplicate words from each line then run word count.
Pig steps:

```
REGISTER 'udf-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar'
define tuple_set com.ts.pig.UniqueRecords();
data = load '<file>' using PigStorage();
```

> remove duplicate words from each line

```
unique= foreach data generate tuple_set($0) as line;
words= foreach unique generate flatten(TOKENIZE(line,' ')) as word;
grouped = group words BY word;
count= foreach grouped GENERATE group, COUNT(words);
dump count;
```

Pig UDF sample code:

```
/**
 * This udf removes duplicate words from line
 */
public class UniqueRecords extends EvalFunc<String> {
    @Override
    public String exec(Tuple tuple) throws IOException {
        if (tuple == null || tuple.size() == 0)
            return null;
        String[] splits=tuple.get(0).toString().split(" ");
        Set<String> elements = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(splits));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(String element:elements ){
            sb.append(element+" ");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually don't quite understand what happens after tokenization. I was trying to do `A = FOREACH input GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(line) ) AS token; B = FOREACH A GENERATE (token matches 'some keyword'? 1 : 0);` I was expecting to get the count of lines that contains this `some keyword`, but it actually returned the number of this `some keyword`, could you please explain how exactly my two lines of code work?

Comment: I would suggest you to read pig basics http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.16.0/start.html